# Insertion sort with strings

Tags: java, sorting

I'm curious how an insertion sort would be for strings. I know how to do with numbers.

Could someone show me an implementation?

No, it's not for homework.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you think it would work with strings?

Answer (score 3):

The sorting algorithm is pretty much the same no matter what you're sorting. The only difference is that with `String`s (or any type of `Object`) you need to use the `compareTo` method rather than simply `if (a < b)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to adapt an insertion sort for numbers to [Strings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) by using [String.compareTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) to determine whether Strings are 'less than' or 'greater than' each other.

Additionally, a quick google search turns up several implementations, like [this one](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/insertion-sort-implementation-in-java.html) which uses the general [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface (which String implements).